# PowerPoint Print to PDF using win32com

Tags: python, pdf, office365, powerpoint

**Goal**: using python, I want to open a Powerpoint presentation and print it using the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer.
I do **NOT** want to export it as PDF, I want to print it using Print to PDF. This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64738521/convert-pptx-to-pdf-using-python-win32com).

**Why**: I have found that in my use case that Print to PDF gives better image quality, whereas Export as PDF is overly compressing the content. Also I do not have Acrobat Pro, so I have no way other than the Office default to export files to PDF.
(For those curious, I have a large .pptx (12Mb, due to some high quality images). Export to PDF generates a PDF that's 1.4Mb large, Print to PDF generates another that's 1.8Mb. The image quality difference is such that one is ok, the other one is not).

**What I have done**: I've figured out how to Export as PDF with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487478/how-to-convert-a-pptx-to-pdf-using-python) (but using `win32com` instead of `comtypes`).

I then tried to change things around so that I'd print instead of save, something like this:

```
powerpoint = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open("prs.pptx")
deck.PrintOut()
deck.Close()
powerpoint.Quit()
```

This almost works, as it's choosing Microsoft Print to PDF as the printer (since it's the default). However, Print to PDF opens a prompt for the file name - and this is where I'm currently stuck. I want to find a way to programmatically deal with the file-dialog-like window and confirm the printing.

I checked whether I wanted `deck.PrintOut(PrintToFile="prs.pdf")`, however this didn't create any file.

**Question**:

1 - Is there a way, using `win32com` or similar, to invoke the `deck.PrintOut()` in a way that it will deal with the extra dialog?
2 - Alternatively, is there a way I can capture the dialog and deal with it?

I'm not too familiar with `win32com` and the documentation seems non-existent, so I wasn't sure what else to try.

Hope this question is sufficiently clear. Many thanks.

Comment: win32com is part of the pywin32 module.  There is a mailing list for help, and there is http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/docindex.html .  Note, however, that win32com is just a way to access COM servers.  To answer your question, you need to look into PowerPoint's object model to see if they have a way to specify a file name.

Comment: I would also point out that the "Export to PDF" task in Office has two options: "standard", intended for publishing, and "minimum size" for online only.  You may be setting the wrong one.

Comment: Generally for win32com (at least the Office parts) I look at the VBA & C# documentation and try to translate. It looks like there is a background option. Try something like `deck.PrintOut(Background=True)`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printoptions.printinbackground and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.options.printbackground?view=word-pia. Also this one from 9 years ago! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993387/python-printing-from-python32

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, I've played around with the export settings - and I am confident I've got everything set up to maximum quality, including the PowerPoint settings about compressing images. I do not have the links at hand now but there are others mentioning that the Office-default Export to PDF can be aggressive on compression, especially when dealing with .png files (my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem above, so I will post as an answer.

It turns out that the attempt to use `PrintOut` was correct [(doc here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.printout)! However I believe this method behaves asynchronously, so in the snippet below:

```
powerpoint = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open("prs.pptx")
deck.PrintOut(PrintToFile="prs.pdf")
deck.Close()
powerpoint.Quit()
```

the print task is aborted by closing the presentation/quitting PowerPoint.

As silly as it sounds, the working code is:

```
powerpoint = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open("prs.pptx")
deck.PrintOut(PrintToFile="prs.pdf")
time.sleep(10)  # Enough time to ensure the print operation is complete
deck.Close()
powerpoint.Quit()
```

I will work on something a little more elegant than a fixed `sleep`, probably a watch on the destination folder, but this resolved my problem. I hope anyone else finds this useful in the future.